# Batch scaling for Deep Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, scaling

I have trained a DNN model in TensorFlow. When I was training my model I did it in batches. After each created batch I was scaling the batch the following way:

```
 batch_x_scale = preprocessing.scale(batch_x)
```

However, I did not know that the scale function is having an attribute axis,  used to compute the means and standard deviations along. If 0, independently standardize each feature, otherwise (if 1) standardize each sample. By default is set to 0.
But where I am using my pre-trained models the input data is a single input, and since is not in batches after scaling my single input in all the value are set to zeros.

My questions are: 
Is there a way to use this model for a single data input (not a batch input)?
If I set the scale axis to 1 and try to train a new model, the new model accuracy is very bad. Is there a recommended method for scaling the data?

P.S. A single row of my data looks like this:

> [0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 23, 75, 1073741824, 6, 2, 4, 1, 1310, 72351744,
>   528594, 203737, 324857, 135362, 10432, 0,
>        0.457309, 0.664461, 93.38, 0.0, 2.56, 4.08, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9699728.0, 5707772.0, 37.05, 35.98, 149.79,
>        43916.95, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4, 3800000000, 4, 17179869184, 1600000000, 4194300.0, 0.0, 0.0, 97.72, 0.0, 1.27,
>        1.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 60612218.0, 5239774.0, 7.955, 42.21, 51530.9, 37659.84, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4,
>        3400000000, 8, 68719476736, 2133000000, 8388604.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1588.224, 96988, 90740.5, 569992, 613586,
>        21595180.5, 8454395.0, 277.57924252922504, 0.0, 0.0, 93170.763733, 215854.80707699998]

Comment: you can use Minmax scaller http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html, but keep in mind any very high deviant values will mess up scalling so use it on a data with lower number of outliers

Comment: but why are you scalling data of each batch ???, that will make inputs completely redundant or devoid of the original characteristics of the data, we do scalling on entire data as it keeps the sanctity intact

Comment: I know now, I was learning and now I learned from my mistake :( 
Thank you for the help I will see what I can do with the Minmax scaler. 
But as you can see the stdev of my data is big, is there any other type of scaler that can do the job better ?